# Is there a way to create an object of co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.Query from a queryString?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api-client

I have a complex Elasticsearch String query which I don't want to create using Java classes.

Is there a way I can achieve it so as to use it something like:

```
Query query = getQueryFromString(queryString);
    
co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchResponse searchResponse = null;
    try {

        co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchRequest request = new co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.core.SearchRequest.Builder()
                .index(indexName)
                .size(pageSize)
                .query(query
                ).build();

        searchResponse = esClient.withTransportOptions(getRequestOptions()).search(request, Object.class);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Some exception occurred while requesting response from elasticsearch", ex);
    }
```

I went through the documentation but couldn't really find a way to achieve so.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with [Wrapper Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wrapper-query.html).

Convert query to [Base64](https://codebeautify.org/json-to-base64-converter#) and run the code bellow.

Query {"match_all": {}} is ewogICAgIm1hdGNoX2FsbCI6IHt9CiAgfQ==.

```
var wrapper = WrapperQuery.of(wq -> wq.query("ewogICAgIm1hdGNoX2FsbCI6IHt9CiAgfQ=="));

var request = SearchRequest.of(sr -> sr
    .index("idx_movies")
    .query(Query.of(q -> q.wrapper(wrapper))));

SearchResponse<Movie> response = ClientUtils.getClient().search(request, Movie.class);
```

Comment: Thanks, @rabbitbr. Can we also do the same for aggregation? Although I understand that it's not a part of the question.

Comment: With aggregations it is not possible. In a project I used json files with queries so I didn't have to write in java. In this [post](https://medium.com/@andre.luiz1987/query-template-with-handlebars-elasticsearch-9ecb375c7cfd) there is a part of what I did. Maybe it will help you.